# Google Analytics 4 and Firebase - How to use unwanted referrals list

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, angularfire2, google-analytics-firebase

I would like to ask how could I exclude unwanted referrals from GA4 and Firebase? In my particular case, I would like to exclude checkout.stripe.com from purchase event sources.

I've added checkout.stripe.com to the unwanted referral list (Data Streams ->  More tagging settings -> List unwanted referrals)

[image]

and specified my domain (Data Streams ->  More tagging settings -> Configure your domain).

[image]

However without a satisfactory result - still each purchase conversion is assigning to checkout.stripe.com

To configure GA4 in my project I'm using the Angularfire library.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know how to fix it.

To filter unwanted referral from GA4 use domain instead subdomain. So in this particular case the proper configuration the "Match type" is "contains" and the domain field to "stripe.com".